# Access SQL query needed (dates)

Tags: ms-access

So i have the following query:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "delete * from [TABLE NAME] where month = '" & Format(PrevMonth, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "'"
```

`month` is a Text field.

Lets say `PrevMonth = August 2010` so instead of delete the rows where the date is august 2010, i want it to delete august 2010 and all after that?  so september 2010, october 2010, and so on.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the CDate() function to cast your text date to date/time data type.

Then:

```
DELETE FROM [TABLE NAME]
WHERE CDate([month]) >= #2010/08/01#;
```

I enclosed the field name in brackets because Month() is an Access VBA function ... the brackets let Access know to treat month as a field rather than the function.  If it were my database, I would rename the field.

Answer (score 1):

First create a query based on [TABLE Name] where you convert month from text to date 


`SELECT *,CDate("1 " & [Month]) AS DateDate

FROM Table Name;`


Now you can use the dates as normal

`DELETE Query1.DateDate

FROM Query1

WHERE (((Query1.DateDate) Between #1/1/2010# And #12/31/2010#));`


Hope this helps

Comment: HansUp version will in one statement, but if CDate fails for any record, my version will allow it easier to check what is going on

Comment: Thanks, i gave you a vote but its not what I am looking for. I am just an intern here and they have me managing an access program with full of spaghetti code programmed by another student. So adding this would further complicate things for the next guy coming in to maintain this.